# Best way of loading images from application bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, image, nsbundle

What is the best way of loading images from the application main bundle. I am using

```
[UIImage imageNamed: "image.png"];
```

But I have heard that this is not good in terms of memory usage and performance. Can anyone please give his/her feedback on it? My application reads lots of images from main bundle at launch time. I want to make this process as efficient as possible.

Best Regards

Comment: You mean: ```[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];```  Forgot the ```@```  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to try loading the images without caching, you can use:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.png"];
```

This could be slightly faster loading the image for the first time, since it doesn't have to cache it first. If you only need to use these images once, it probably makes sense to try it this way. The other benefit of doing it this way is that you won't have an image cache using up memory for longer than necessary.

Comment: The question is about memory usage and performance when loading images, not the best way to get a list of image files from the bundle. If he has a lot of images, then the alternative way of loading them that may provide better performance is what I described.

Comment: if you read the whole question carefully, you will get the answer what he wants.

Comment: @Mudit, How this is not the best way for lots of images? Can you please explain it in more detail so that I get a clear picture? Thanks

Comment: @MuditBajpai As I have understood, path array is being used to just give the path of a specific image. Rest of thing is being managed by initWithContentsOfFile method of UIImage. Right?

Comment: So What I have understood from this discussion is that I should go with initWithContentsOfFile method if I dont caching. Since I dont want caching, I would prefer to go with above method. Am I gonna do right thing??? :-)

Answer (score 13):

If there were one true "Best Way", the means to load images multiple ways would not exist (unless for historical reasons). Therefore, a little understanding will serve you better than distilling an answer down to a "Best Way".

`+[UIImage imageNamed:]` caches the image for reuse, and it is a sensible default for most purposes. Caching is *excellent* if used correctly. The cache is good because it can minimize your disk reads and memory usage by sharing and reusing loaded images, rather than reading and allocating a copy for each image you must display. Consider an icon image which you use on multiple screens - would you like that image data to be read and reallocated each time? This may result in redundant reads and allocations of identical image data. If not, use the caching methods.

If you load the image only once and lazily, then you may want consider non-caching approaches.

- Image data can consume a lot of memory.
- Reading an image can take a long time -- not just disk i/o, but also converting it into a usable UIImage representation (e.g. decompressing the image).
- there are also times where you should resize/scale an image. then you'd want a scaled copy.

In short, there are many considerations, but if you have properly scaled assets which you reuse, caching is typically the right choice.

If your assets are not sized properly, then the issue is more fundamental -- you should resize the bundled assets to be appropriate for the purpose if you're experiencing performance problems. Properly sized images also make drawing significantly simpler while retaining the best image quality.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Yeah this is why I want the best way of loading images. My app takes lot of time while processing these images thats why I was wondering if i could improve my code.

Comment: @Aqueel I've just edited the answer to cover using proper sizes - have a look.

Comment: Justin, your feedback was really helpful. I was using around 15 large size images and scaling them before using which I will fix now. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 10):

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimage" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding a single resource file using NSBundle

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSString* myImage = [myBundle pathForResource:@"Seagull" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

and for finding multiple resources:

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

NSArray* myImages = [myBundle pathsForResourcesOfType:@"jpg"
                              inDirectory:nil];
```

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question.

Comment: Hi I am not looking for finding a mechanism for creating a path of the image. I want something which can improve memory usage and performance when I load images from main bundle.

Comment: ya i know, the second option is also the better way related to performance  issue if you have multiple images.